# Случайный вектор в полусфере в пределах заданного угла (наиболее оптимальный алгоритм)

Tags: математика, raytracing

При трассировке лучей нередко возникает необходимость генерировать случайный вектор в пределах полусферы, отклоненный от исходного на какой-то заданный угол. На просторах интернета не нашлось внятных и развернутых ответов на данный вопрос. Хоть в математике я не шибко силен, все же хотелось бы понимать что происходит, а не просто брать готовую формулу.

**Еще раз вкратце о сути задачи:**

Есть какой-то вектор, есть какой-то угол (обычно в таких ситуациях его называют телесным углом, но могу ошибаться), необходимо выбрать какой-то случайный вектор, который находился бы в пределах этого самого угла. Угол может быть все 180 градусов, и охватывать всю полусферу.

Понимаю, что задача стара как мир, но все же, хотелось бы, чтобы кто-то разжевал тупому гуманитарию как это правильно делается. Причем можно привести наиболее оптимальный с точки зрения математики пример, а также пример наиболее оптимальный с точки зрения кода. Нередко они разнятся. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вначале сгенерируем вектор, перпендикулярный данному `A`

Для этого найдём наибольший и второй по амплитуде компоненты `A`. Пусть это `A.Y` и `A.Z`.

Теперь создадим вектор `B = (0, A.Z, -A.Y)` - т.е. обнулим наименьший компонент, а два больших обменяем и изменим знак одного из компонентов. Можно заметить, что скалярное произведение `A.dot.B` равно нулю, т.е. векторы перпендикулярны.

Теперь создадим ещё один вектор `C = A x B`, используя векторное произведение. Он перпендикулярен как `A`, так и `B`.

Нормализуем `B` и `С` (разделим на длину)

Выберем случайный угол `fi` в диапазоне `0..2*Pi` и создадим вектор

```
D = B * cos(fi) + C * sin(fi)
```

Получился случайный единичный вектор, который лежит в плоскости, нормальной `A`

Теперь выберем случайный угол `theta` в  `в пределах этого самого угла` (т.е. до `Pi/2` или меньше)  и сделаем искомый вектор (да, `A` нормализован)

```
E = A * cos(theta) + D * sin(theta)
```

Comment: Благодарю. Просто и вроде как действительно должно сработать. Не знал что перпендикулярные вектора можно получать таким образом (сменой компонентов и заменой знака). Обычно я такой вектор получал векторным произведением немного отклоненного в сторону вектора

Comment: Подумал еще немного, и возник вопрос - а не выйдет ли, если делать таким образом, что область где распределяются эти случайные вектора, будет в виде не круглого конуса, а прямоугольного? Например, если углы будут от -30 до 30, то если, например fi будет 30, и угол theta тоже.. это создаст вектор который смотрит в угол такого прямоугольного конуса.. или я ошибаюсь и конус распределения случайных векторов все же с круглым основанием?

Comment: Нет, не будет. Вектор D распределён по кругу, для него нет выделенных направлений

Comment: Протестировал, не сработало.. Причем я заметил что у вас, в ответе, вектор C никак не задействован в подсчете итогового вектора. Я попробовал сделать D = A * cos(fi) + B * sin(fi), E = A * cos(theta) + C * sin(theta), это кажется логичным, ну и затем сложить С и D, тогда работает, но распределение получается по квадрату, чего я и опасался.. та формула что вы указали - (E = A * cos(theta) + D * sin(theta)) именно таковой задумывалась?

Comment: Да, конечно, ошибка - исправил на `D = B * cos(fi) + C * sin(fi)`. Если, например, B  единичный вектор (1,0,0), а C=(0,1,0), то D будет лежать на единичной окружности в плоскости OXY

Comment: Теперь наконец понял. Да, всё работает. Еще раз спасибо.